# How to fix "the type or namespace TTransactionKey could not be found" error

Tags: c#

I am building a class that requires generics but some can't be found although I used them before.

```
public class Bank<TClient, TAbstractAccount, TTransaction> : AbstractBank<TClient, TAbstractAccount, TTransaction>
     where TClient : Client<TTransactionKey, TAccountKey, TAccountEntity, TTransaction>

       //where TAbstractAccount : AbstractAccount<TClientKey, TTransactionEntity, TAccountKey, TTransactionKey>

    {
    public Bank(string bankName, int swiftCode) : base(bankName, swiftCode)
    {
        Agents = 1;
    }

    public override void AddTransaction(TTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (Agents > 0)
        {
            lock (TransactionsQueue)
            {
                TransactionsQueue.Enqueue(transaction);
                   // TAbstractAccount source = 

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type parameters available for use in a type parameter constraint on a generic class declaration are a subset of the type parameters of the generic class, and those of its enclosing class types.

eg

```
class Foo<T1,T2,T3> where T1: Bar<T4>
```

Is illegal because the `T4` isn't a type parameter of Foo. But

```
class Foo<T1, T2, T3, T4> where T1 : Bar<T4>
```

is legal.  And

```
class Baz<T4>
{
    class Foo<T1, T2, T3> where T1 : Bar<T4>
    {

    }
}
```

Is legal.